# How to add a link to a jsp page in an adf tree node?

Tags: oracle-adf

I have made an adf tree but I am not able to add links to each child node.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mentioned that whether or not you are in WebCenter Portal application. But if you are in Portal Application you can take help of NavigationContext for navigation, you can find more information and examples in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25178_01/webcenter.1111/e10148/jpsdg_view_comps.htm). Also you can use NavigationContext from backing bean. You could define actionListener of your commandLink and from that method you can navigate to the various pages from backend as well as from the jspx page.

If you are not in Portal application, in Fusion Web Application you should define your navigation by control-flow-case of adfc-config.xml. Don't use FacesConfig for navigation. Read this [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/b31974/taskflows.htm) to know how navigation system works.

Since you are in a Tree Model and if you need to parameter then you can set some value to session as:

```
<af:tree value="#{ConnectorTest.model}" var="node" > 
     <af:commandLink text="#{node.text}" action="#{node.action}">
          <af:setPropertyListener from="#{node.value}" to="#{sessionScope.value}" type="action"/>
     </af:commandLink>
</af:tree>
```

here the action will be defined in adfc-config. If you don't need to pass parameter then ignore the af:setPropertyListener but you should define the action in config file.

Hope this will help.

---

Edit:

Suppose you have two pages: Page1.jspx and Page2.jspx. Now you need to define the action (specifically from-action) in adfc-config.xml as following way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<adfc-config xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/controller" version="1.2">
  <view id="p1">
    <page>/path-to-the/Page1.jspx</page>
  </view>
  <view id="p2">
    <page>/path-to-the/Page2.jspx</page>
  </view>

  <control-flow-rule>
    <from-activity-id>p1</from-activity-id>
    <control-flow-case>
      <from-outcome>goToP2</from-outcome>
      <to-activity-id>p2</to-activity-id>
    </control-flow-case>
  </control-flow-rule>
</adfc-config>
```

Now if you have a commandLink:
`<af:commandLink id="link" action="goToP2" />` will navigate you to the Page2.jspx. The action attribute also accept el expression.

Comment: It didn't work. I have to retrieve the value of each node then set an action according to the clicked node. i.e if a particular node is clicked then a respective jsp should open. this is my tree - http://yonaweb.be/creating_your_own_treemodel_adf_11g_0

Comment: @SumitJha where did you defined your actions?

Comment: the only action i have defined is in the commandlink
<af:commandLink text="#{node.text}" action="#{node.action}">

Comment: but how to trigger this action on click of a node?

Comment: You don't need to trigger this action programmatically, it will automatically triggered up. You might need a wild-card controll flow.

Answer (score 0):

Have u mean to add hyperlink on child node?

```
<af:tree var="node" value="#{myBean.myTree.root}" id="t1" focusListener="#{myBean.eventMethod}">
<af:commandLink text="#{node.firstname}" />
</af:tree>
```

when u click on node it fire focus event and call method eventMethod that accepts FocusEvent obj as arguments, in this method u set navigation rule etc etc.....

try it

Comment: Yes, adding hyperlink to each child nodes in the tree and different child nodes points to different html/jsp pages.

Comment: this is my tree:
 <af:tree value="#{ConnectorTest.model}" var="node" >
          <f:facet name="nodeStamp">
            <af:commandLink  text="#{node.text}" action="#{node.action}"/>
Connector tree is my java class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<af:switcher>` tag, if you want to display different action, for different child nodes